# Create local link in rotated PdfPCell in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, hyperlink, itext

I'm trying to put a link to another page in my pdf using iTextSharp. 
link in rotated cell is not working. other cells work as expected:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("TestPDF.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
doc.Open();

PdfPTable linkTable = new PdfPTable(2);
PdfPCell linkCell = new PdfPCell();

linkCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
linkCell.Rotation = 90;
linkCell.FixedHeight = 70;

Anchor linkAnchor = new Anchor("Click here");
linkAnchor.Reference = "#target";
Paragraph linkPara = new Paragraph();
linkPara.Add(linkAnchor);
linkCell.AddElement(linkPara);
linkTable.AddCell(linkCell);

PdfPCell linkCell2 = new PdfPCell();
Anchor linkAnchor2 = new Anchor("Click here 2");
linkAnchor2.Reference = "#target";
Paragraph linkPara2 = new Paragraph();
linkPara2.Add(linkAnchor2);
linkCell2.AddElement(linkPara2);
linkTable.AddCell(linkCell2);

linkTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell 3")));
linkTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell 4")));
doc.Add(linkTable);

doc.NewPage();

Anchor destAnchor = new Anchor("top");
destAnchor.Name = "target";
PdfPTable destTable = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell destCell = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph destPara = new Paragraph();
destPara.Add(destAnchor);
destCell.AddElement(destPara);
destTable.AddCell(destCell);
destTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell 2")));
destTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell 3")));
destTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell 4")));
doc.Add(destTable);

doc.Close();
```

I'm using 'iTextSharp 5.5.8'. I've tried with Chunk.SetAction PdfAction.GotoLocalPage and Chunk.SetLocalGoto. Nothing works for me

Thank you.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @blagae oh sorry, it works outside of the pdftable but inside it is normal text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually iText(Sharp) did create a **Link** annotation for the anchor in the rotated cell, too, but its coordinates are completely wrong:

```
/Rect[-0.003 0 53.34 12]
```

These coordinates even are partially off-page which might explain peculiar behavior of some PDF viewers.

### The cause

(I analyzed the iText Java code which has the same issues, because I'm more at home with Java. The matching iTextSharp C# code is very similar, though.)

The cause for this is that the `PdfDocument` code processing a `PdfChunk` assumes that the current coordinate system is the original user space coordinate system initialized with the **MediaBox** data. Thus, it uses the current coordinates without any transformation to generate local **Link** annotations:

```
float xMarker = text.getXTLM();
float baseXMarker = xMarker;
float yMarker = text.getYTLM();
...
if (chunk.isAttribute(Chunk.LOCALGOTO)) {
    float subtract = lastBaseFactor;
    if (nextChunk != null && nextChunk.isAttribute(Chunk.LOCALGOTO))
        subtract = 0;
    if (nextChunk == null)
        subtract += hangingCorrection;
    localGoto((String)chunk.getAttribute(Chunk.LOCALGOTO), xMarker, yMarker, xMarker + width - subtract, yMarker + fontSize);
}
```

*(PdfDocument.writeLineToContent(PdfLine, PdfContentByte, PdfContentByte, Object[], float))*

Unfortunately, though, cell rotation is implemented by means of a user coordinate system change, e.g. a rotation by 90°:

```
ct.setSimpleColumn(-0.003f, -0.001f, netWidth + 0.003f, calcHeight);
...
pivotY = cell.getTop() + yPos - currentMaxHeight + cell.getEffectivePaddingBottom();
switch (cell.getVerticalAlignment()) {
    case Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM:
        pivotX = cell.getLeft() + xPos + cell.getWidth() - cell.getEffectivePaddingRight();
        break;
    case Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE:
        pivotX = cell.getLeft() + xPos + (cell.getWidth() + cell.getEffectivePaddingLeft() - cell.getEffectivePaddingRight() + calcHeight) / 2;
        break;
    default: //top
        pivotX = cell.getLeft() + xPos + cell.getEffectivePaddingLeft() + calcHeight;
        break;
}
saveAndRotateCanvases(canvases, 0, 1, -1, 0, pivotX, pivotY);
```

*(PdfPRow.writeCells(int, int, float, float, PdfContentByte[], boolean))*

Thus, the `PdfDocument` code above called for a rotated anchor chunk will position at a generally completely wrong position.

By the way, this does not only concern local **Link** annotations but all kinds of annotations generated for a chunk. A particularly evil case is that of a generic tag: if a page event listener reacts to a `GenericTag` event, it can use the coordinates for some drawing action during the call but not as coordinates relative to the **MediaBox**.

---

A fix for this most likely requires signaling any coordinate system changes to the `PdfDocument` and updating the code there to take this information into account when using coordinates for purposes not influenced by those transformations. In particular the `GenericTag` event should be extended to receive both the transformed and the original coordinates.

I would propose leaving this fix to iText development.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. I have created an internal dev ticket for this bug.

Comment: Hello, it's been a while, are you planning to fix this bug?

Comment: @Tubc I'm afraid the bug persists, it even is present in iText 7, cf. [this Java test](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/annotate/CreateLink.java).

Answer (score 2):

It would have been useful to include the code that is not working for you, so people can focus on the specific issue(s).

I have verified creating local links in general, when both link and destination are in a table (i.e. `PdfPCell`).  This code works as expected:

```
PdfPTable linkTable = new PdfPTable(2);
PdfPCell linkCell = new PdfPCell();
Anchor linkAnchor = new Anchor("Click here to go to top of next page.");
linkAnchor.Reference = "#target";
Paragraph linkPara = new Paragraph();
linkPara.Add(linkAnchor);
linkCell.AddElement(linkPara);
linkTable.AddCell(linkCell);
linkTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell 2")));
linkTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell 3")));
linkTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell 4")));
doc.Add(linkTable);

doc.NewPage();

Anchor destAnchor = new Anchor("top");
destAnchor.Name = "target";
PdfPTable destTable = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell destCell = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph destPara = new Paragraph();
destPara.Add(destAnchor);
destCell.AddElement(destPara);
destTable.AddCell(destCell);
destTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell 2")));
destTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell 3")));
destTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell 4")));
doc.Add(destTable);
```

Comment: I use the exactly same code as you, I've just figured out that because I rotate the cell by 90 then the link disappear. I'll update my question.

Comment: @BuiCaoTu Maybe you're using an obsolete version of iText. Maybe you're talking about a bug that was fixed years ago...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I updated iTextSharp 5.5.8, still not work, I edited with full code that I'm using

Comment: @rhens Can you check what happens when rotation is involved? That seems to be an important difference between your code and the code by the OP.

Comment: @Tubc As rotation seems to make the difference, have you checked whether the link simply is in a different region on the page?

Comment: @mkl there is no link at all

Comment: @Tubc I just tested your code. The missing active link area is located at the very bottom of the page, near the left side.

Comment: @Tubc Well, when I click that area, the view jumps, so it works in a way. Obviously, though, the active link area position is all wrong

Comment: @mkl it's not working for me maybe it depends on the reader. so what can we do about it?

Comment: If it depends on the viewer, that's yet another issue. Which one do you use? I used the Adobe Acrobat Reader DC on Windows.

Comment: @mkl Adobe Reader XI, Reader in Windows 8 show working link as a single point at e letter, in Google Chrome I don't see the link, foxit reader has a working link at bottom like yours

Comment: The link annotation position starts slightly off-page. this may make some viewers behave peculiar.