# Itext PDF Cell rotation loses hyperlink

Tags: java, pdf, hyperlink, itext

I am trying to create a lateral table with one of the cells being a hyperlink to a web site with iText 5.5.8. If I create a horizontal table, the result is ok:

```
        File file = new File("c://temp//itext-test.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileout);
        document.open();
        String stampedURL = "http://test.com";
        URL validaURL = new URL(stampedURL);

    try {

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3); // 3 columns.
        PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell();
        Chunk paragr = new Chunk("Click Here!");
        PdfAction pdfAct = new PdfAction(validaURL);
        paragr.setAction(pdfAct);
        paragr.setAnchor(validaURL);
        cell1.addElement(paragr);
        PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 2"));
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 3"));

        table.addCell(cell1);
        table.addCell(cell2);
        table.addCell(cell3);

        document.add(table);
        document.close();
    } catch(Exception e){

    }
```

This code generates a horizontal table with 3 cells. The first one, contains an anchor and a pdfAction to a certain URL, so it is working fine.

To rotate the table, I simply rotate 90 degrees every cell. So before adding the cells to the table, I do:

```
 cell1.setRotation(90);
 cell2.setRotation(90);
 cell3.setRotation(90);
```

Now I have rotated the cells, but the hyperlink has disappeared. I have been trying with several combinations, but with no luck.

Just to see if it was possible, I created a Word Document with rotated hyperlink in a cell, and then converted to PDF, and the link works... I know it is not a very helpful test, but just to try.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Thanks in advanced,

Xisco.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create local link in rotated PdfPCell in iTextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408764/create-local-link-in-rotated-pdfpcell-in-itextsharp) - both iText and iTextSharp have the same bug.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to a similar post. I thought it was something relative to the java version. I read in that post that a internal bug has been opened regarding this question.

Comment: *I thought it was something relative to the java version.* Unfortunately no, the issue occurs both with iText and with iTextSharp. *I read in that post that a internal bug has been opened regarding this question.* - Yes, it has, but I have not yet heard about it been resolved.